# If $A$ is a set then $A/R$ is a set.

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I just started reading some notes on set theory, and I am still a confused as how to use the different axioms to determine that something is a set.

For example, I wan't to say that given a set A and an equivalence relation $R$, $A/R$ is a set. So I start by saying that from the comprehension axiom (if $z$ is a set and $\phi$ a formula, then $\{x\in z \mid \phi \}$ is a set) the equivalence classes is a set because $[x]=\{y\in A \mid y\}$. Then using that by the power set axiom $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is  a set and again by comprehension I have that $\{[x]\in \mathcal{P}(A) \mid x\in A\}$ is a set. Is this the correct reasoning?

Comment: $\{[x]\in \mathcal{P}(A)\mid x\in A\}$ is not properly written as a set obtained by comprehension, since $x\in A$ is not a formula that you evaluate on $[x]$. You could write it as $\{x\in \mathcal{P}(A)\mid \forall y\in x\forall z\in x,\ \{\{y\},\{y,z\}\}\in R \wedge \forall t\in A (\exists r\in x\{\{t\},\{t,x\}\}\in R\implies t\in x)\}$. Here the condition $\forall y\in x\forall z\in x,\ \{\{y\},\{y,z\}\}\in R$ expresses that all elements of $x$ are related by $R$, while the condition $\forall t\in A (\exists r\in x\{\{t\},\{t,x\}\}\in R\implies t\in x)$ expresses that ...

Comment: ... $x$ is maximal, namely that all elements $t$ that are related by $R$ to some element $z$ of $x$ are already in $x$.

Comment: Another way, that you could write it, closer to the spirit of what you wrote could be $\{z\in A\mid \exists x\in A(z=[x])\}$. Note how this has the form $\{z\in B\mid \phi(z,r_1,r_2,...,r_n,B)\}$, where $\phi$ is a formula in which one of its free variables is evaluated in $z$. Compare to your $x\in A$, which is a formula that its free variable is evaluated in $x$, rather than $[x]$. The latter doesn't determine $x$.

Answer (score 2):

First comprehension tells us that for each $x \in A$

$$[x]:=\{y \in A \mid (x,y) \in R\}$$ is a well defined set.

Then $$A{/}R = \{B \in \mathscr{P}(A): \exists x \in A: B=[x]\}$$

is well-defined with the power set axiom and comprehension again.

Your way of writing $$A{/}R = \{[x]: x \in A\}$$

appeals to the axiom of replacement instead (using that $x \to [x]$ is a "set function", applying it to the "domain" $A$). It depends on what you want, really. In ZF both are OK.

Answer (score 0):

That looks good. Except a typo. I imagine you meant

$$[x]=\{y\in A \mid (x,y)\in R\}$$